# Customizing share content based on what is selected in UIActivityController

Tags: ios, share, uiactivityviewcontroller

I want to change the content of the message body on what type of share the user has chosen, how do I do that? Right now I can set one value when it is initialized, how do I change it? any pointers appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `UIActivityItemSource` protocol method [`activityViewController:itemForActivityType:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityItemSource_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIActivityItemSource/activityViewController:itemForActivityType:).

Check the activity type and return a different NSString for the message that you want displayed.

The types are listed in the [UIActivity class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivity_Class/index.html).